# Does losing the use of a feat also prevent the use of feats that have that feat as a prerrequisite?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, feat-qualifications

I've seen many similar questions but I've not seen this exactly answered.

Let's say that I'm rolling a 10 Int character and gets a temporary buff to Int by an item that let's him pick Combat Expertise. Sometime after, he picks the item again on a level up and picks Karmic Strike. If he loses the Int bonus, aside from the use of Combat Expertise, does he also lose the use of Karmic Strike due to losing the use of Combat Expertise?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80460/8610), [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23120/8610), [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23119/8610), or [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60089/8610). Take your pick! `:-)`

Comment: That does not really answer my question since you don't really lose the feat itself, only its use, but I'm not sure how the ruling works on that.

Comment: So then [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/23121/8610) (i.e. the second one).

Comment: *facepalm* Yes, you're right, I'm kinda dense today.

Comment: To be fair—to you!—it's a really complicated topic. I mean, at the time of this writing, three people agree that this is a fine question despite it being a duplicate. `:-)`